# Git SVN clone with complex structure

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I need to clone an SVN repository to git. The SVN repository is structured as if it's a repository of repositories, like so:

```
SVNRepo
|____ProjectA
|    |___branches
|    |___tags
|    |___trunk
|            file
|____ProjectB
|    |___branches
|    |___tags
|    |___trunk
             file
```

I need to clone the repository so that I end up with a single git repository, without the svn specific folders (branches, tags, trunk). I originally dumped then split the SVN repo into separate repos for each project and migrated to git using git svn clone with the --stdlayout command. This worked but came with it's own issues that have been vetoed by our team.

I tried the git svn clone **with** the --stdlayout command but that doesn't work. I end up with an empty git repo with 2 commits (out of hundreds) and no actual files. There were no errors so I'm not sure what happened.

Trying git svn clone **without** the --stdlayout sort of works, in that I get a single git repo with all files and history. However, I still have all of the branches, tags and trunk folders which I've like to remove.

I've considered dumping the SVN repo and using sed to edit the binary but that seems like a lot of work. I imagine someone else has encountered this and solved the problem but can't find anything that works.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up multiple trunk, branches and tags locations in git svn's configuration. If they are being created from the same parents, git-svn will figure it out. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn

Comment: Are you referring to "You can specify more than one --tags and/or --branches options"? If so, could you provide a basic example please?

Comment: If you want to know how to specify them in the ```git svn init``` call, then yes, you can provide the "base" url to the repository and then provide multiple locations for _separate_ branches (using --trunk), _grouped_ branches (using --branches) and tags. So, in your case, it should look something like: git svn init -T ProjectA/trunk -B ProjectA/branches -t ProjectA/tags -T ProjectB/trunk -b ProjectB/branches -t ProjectB/tags. But now I'm wondering... are they the same project? Cause if they are not then you should consider creating a separate repo for each project.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it and post back. The actual SVN repository has 13 projects inside it. Many of them are dependent on each other to build, but not all. I originally separated them out and used them as git submodules, but I had issues were projA would depend on projB and projC, whilst projB would also depend on projC. Trying to organise it so projC only got checked out once was a PITA.

Comment: I guess you could keep them separate and tie them together with something like gradle or maven (if using Java, anyway.... I'm sure there are other things available for other languages). Just elaborating, anyway.

Comment: My original suggestions was to use a package manager but again that was vetoed. :(

Comment: Then time for some unorthodox "out of the box" thinking. :-)

Comment: I tried as you suggested and unfortunately it doesn't work. If --trunk is specified more than once, only the last instance is used i.e. in your example, only ProjectB is cloned.

Comment: Edit .git/config manually to add the other locations for trunk/branches/tags. That's what I've done other times.

Answer (score 0):

For a one-time migration `git-svn` is **not** the right tool for conversions of repositories or repository parts. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are plenty tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will be easily able to configure `svn2git`s rule file to produce the result you want from your current SVN layout.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

You see, there are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)