# Setting up git-svn repository where svn trunk/tags/branches are organized in module subfolders

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I want to set up git locally (using git-svn) on my companies svn that has the following structure:

- Module1

  - trunk
  - branches
  - tags

    - tag1
    - tag2
- Module2

  - trunk
  - branches
  - tags
- ...

I tried to use `git svn clone /remote/path/to/svn/repo -s` but the trunk/brances/tags structure is not standard. I guess I could specify all trunk/branches/tags by explicitly writing `-T /local/path/to/module1/trunk -T /local/path/to/module2/trunk` etc, which would be pretty cumbersome as there are many modules in the project. Is this the right way  to go?

My question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43095525/git-svn-clone-with-complex-structure) but I didn't find the answers satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up checking out a separate git repository for each module (that I am actively working on). Not 100% satisfactory but at least I can work with local commits and (lightweight) feature branches